# How to get specific value in an array based on the another value using PHP

Tags: php

I am having a problem getting the right value in the array. I have an array that has a key of moq and costunit. I want to get the costunit if the given quantity is greater than or equal to the moq. I have the following array.

```
Array
(
    [moq] => 1000
    [costunit] => 0.44
)
Array
(
    [moq] => 20000
    [costunit] => 0.33
)
Array
(
    [moq] => 30000
    [costunit] => 0.30
)
```

Example 1: if the given qty is 25000 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.33

Example 2: if the given qty is 1230 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.44

```
$get_prices = array(
  array( 'moq'=> 1000,  'costunit'=> 0.44 ),
  array( 'moq'=> 20000, 'costunit'=> 0.33 ),
  array( 'moq'=> 30000, 'costunit'=> 0.30 ),
);
$get_quantity = 30000;
foreach($get_prices as $get_price){

  if($get_price['moq'] >= $get_quantity){
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($get_price['costunit']);
    echo '</pre>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the code is doing exactly what you requirement specified. So maybe your spec is what is wrong

Comment: The code posted in the question does not compile. It needs commas after the values in the array.

Comment: _"if the given qty is 1230 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.44"_ - why? You said, _"if the moq is greater or equal to the given quantity"_ - the `moq` of `1000` _is not_ greater than your given quantity of 1230.

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated my question. What I want is to get the costunit of moq is above or equal the given quantity.Example 1: if the given qty is 25000 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.33

Comment: No, both of your examples do not match your verbal specification! Please take a breath and have a second look at what you want the code to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry should I say less than? Because what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the value of cost unit if given quantity is above the current moq. If MOQ is 1000 and the current quantity is 1250 then I should get 0.44. Sorry if I'm not clear..

Comment: No, not less, but more accurate. If you are sure you want to pass a value of `25000` to the algorithm and be returned a `costunit` of `0.33` then re-specify your spec, likely then you will see whats wrong with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I think you need is a `break` in the loop so it stops when it find the first valid value

```
$get_prices = array(
  array( 'moq'=> 1000, 'costunit'=> 0.44 ),
  array( 'moq'=> 20000,'costunit'=> 0.33 ),
  array( 'moq'=> 30000, 'costunit'=> 0.30 )
);
$get_quantity = 1250;
foreach($get_prices as $get_price){

  if($get_price['moq'] >= $get_quantity){
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($get_price['costunit']);
    echo '</pre>';
    break;
   }
}
```

RESULT

```
<pre>0.33</pre>
```

> NOTE: I think your examples are wrong, have another look at what you said because it seems it is exactly what the code did, apart from not stopping when it found the first valid value

---

If as you say these are the rules

> If the given qty is 25000 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.33
>
> If the given qty is 1230 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.44

Then this code will do that, however, you will have to decide what to set `$prev_cu` to so you get the right value if the `$get_quantity` is less than the `moq` in the first occurance of the array.

```
$get_prices = array(
    array( 'moq'=> 1000, 'costunit'=> 0.44 ),
    array( 'moq'=> 20000,'costunit'=> 0.33 ),
    array( 'moq'=> 30000, 'costunit'=> 0.30 )
);

$get_quantity = 25000;
// set a costunit to use if qty is less than occ 0 of array
$prev_cu = 0;   

foreach ($get_prices as $get_price) {
    if ($get_quantity < $get_price['moq'] ) {
        break;
    }
    if ($get_quantity == $get_price['moq'] ) {
        $prev_cu = $get_price['costunit'];
        break;
    }
    $prev_cu = $get_price['costunit'];
}
echo $prev_cu;
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated my question. What I want is to get the costunit of moq is above or equal the given quantity.Example 1: if the given qty is 25000 then the cost unit would be displayed is 0.33

Comment: Look at the requirement!! The `costunit` that matches that requirement of a `moq` GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 25000 is the `moq` of `30000` which is `0.30`

Comment: @NeverStopLearning Get your specifications right.

Comment: I have added a second set of code to match the examples you give